# Alternative solution to if else if else if else trees?

Tags: c#, razor

I have a problem where I need to account for every combination of possible options of 4 booleans. e.g.

I have 4 booleans, useFeatured, groupBy, orderBy & ascending. Possible combinations are..

```
featured.
featured & orderby.
featured & orderby & groupby.
featured & orderby & groupby & ascending.

featured & groupby.
featured & groupby & ascending.

featured & ascending
featured & ascedning & orderby

orderby
orderby & groupby
orderby & groupby & ascending

groupby
groupby & ascending

ascending
ascending & orderby
```

At the moment I have a huge if else if else tree for these options and I find it really hard to believe it's the only solutions, but I cant think of anything else.

Here is a link to the if else tree.

```
if(featured){
if(orderby){
    if(groupby){
            if(ascedning){
                    //featured orderby groupby ascending
            }else{
                    //featured orderby groupby
            }
    }else{
            //featured orderby
    }
}else if(groupby){
    if(ascedning){
            //featured groupby ascending
    }else{
            //featured groupby
    }
}else if(ascending){
    if(orderby){
            //featured ascending orderby
    }else{
            //featured ascending
    }
}else{
    //featured
}
 }else if(orderby){
    if(groupby){
            if(ascending){
                    //orderby groupby ascending
            }else{
                    //orderby groupby
            }
    }
}else if(groupby){
    if(ascending){
            //groupby ascending
    }else{
            //groupvy
    }
 }else if(ascending){
    if(orderby){
            //ascending & orderby
    }else{
            //ascending
    }
 }else{
    //orderby
 }
```

Pastebin if mess formatting up. http://pastebin.com/ECgASU3C

Anyone got a better solution I can adopt? Please save me!

Comment: A [decision table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_table) would be a good fit...

Comment: whar is your code inside single if: linq-to-sql query?

Comment: stuff like this

orderedNodeList = nodeList.OrderBy(x => x.GetPropertyValue("featured")).ThenByDescending(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.GetPropertyValue(orderBy)));

Comment: I'm not sure, but aren't those bools more or less independent from each other?

Comment: Decision table implementation in C#: http://lukevoss.com/blog/post/2008/09/Decision-Table-in-C.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can use **switch case** for this...but **if else** is better option